# Extend Optional to check whether it is nil or false

Tags: swift

I want to extend the `Optional` class to return a Bool indicating whether `self` is `nil` or `false`. How do I do this?

I already have an extension for optional to check if it is empty or `nil` like this:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: Collection {
    var isNilOrEmpty: Bool {
        return self?.isEmpty ?? true
    }
}
```

So it needs to be something along those lines but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Not what you are asking but you can simply add to your optionalBool `== true` or `== false`. `if optionalBool == true { // do this`

Comment: Do you want to have that extension or an optional `Bool`? Note that such extensions are generally frowned upon because they don't make your code shorter but they make it less readable.

Comment: I agree with the comments above. It is tempting to be able to use bools directly (ie without the need to compare with true or false) and most of the time you'll be just fine, but it would also increase the possibility for errors since `Bool?` (unlike the non-optional one) has _three_ possible states and code like this is encouraging non-handling of the "unset" state.

Comment: By the way, even using optional `Bool` is sometimes discouraged because it represents a `Bool` that has 3 values. Sometimes it's better to just use a non-optional enum with 3 values.

Comment: If you find yourself needing anything like `isNilOrEmpty`, you have almost certainly used the wrong type. If there is no difference between empty and nil, this variable should be the the collection, not an Optional. The same is true of Bool. If there is no difference between false and nil, then the variable should be a Bool, not an Optional. `Bool?` should only be used in cases where false and nil have different meanings.

Comment: For readability, I think `self?.dataArray.isNilOrEmpty` would be more readable than `self?.dataArray.isEmpty == false`. Also, not a fan of wrapping the statement `(self?.dataArray).isNilOrEmpty`. The problem is with chain optional, where `optionalArray.isNilOrEmpty` will compile but equally meaning `myClass?.optionalArray.isNilOrEmpty` will not.

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt, unwrap using `guard`:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == Bool {
    var isNilOrFalse: Bool {
        guard let wrapped = self else { return true }
        return !wrapped
    }
}
```

Which can be shortened to:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == Bool {
    var isNilOrFalse: Bool {
        return !(self ?? false)
    }
}
```

but since short is not always the most readable, I would personally use explicit:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == Bool {
    var isNilOrFalse: Bool {
        return self == nil || self == false
    }
}
```

However, I would warn against using such extensions. They don't make your code more readable.

Comment: IMHO `return !(self == true)` is easier to understand than `!(self ?? false)`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I think there are no winners in this case :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import Foundation

extension Optional where Wrapped == String { 
    var isNotBlank: Bool {
        if let a = self, a.isNotEmpty {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    var isBlank: Bool {
        return !isNotBlank
    }
}

extension Optional {
    var isNil: Bool {
        return self == nil
    }

    var isNotNil: Bool {
        return self != nil
    }

    func ifLet(_ action: (Wrapped)-> Void) {
        if self != nil {
            action(self.unsafelyUnwrapped)
        }
        else { return }
    }

    func ifNil (_ action: ()-> Void) {
        if self == nil { action() }
        else { return }
    }

    func ifElse(_ notNil: ()-> Void, _ isNil: ()-> Void) {
        if self != nil { notNil() }
        else { isNil() }
    }

    func or<T>(_ opt: T) -> T {
        if self == nil { return opt }
        else { return self as! T }
    }

    mutating func orChange<T>(_ opt: T) {
        if self == nil { self = opt as? Wrapped }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything new. You can use `!= true` on an optional Bool:

```
var aBool: Bool? = nil

if aBool != true {
    print("aBool is nil or false")
}
```

That is legal and works. It works because nil is not equal to true.

Comment: It 'would' be nice if I could ask `optionalClass?.isMyStatementCorrect.notNilTrue` rather than `optionalClass?.isMyStatementCorrect == true`. And why should the meaning be different than 'is' `(optionalClass?.isMyStatementCorrect).notNilTrue`? (When the optional is chained behind)